# git conflict - file deleted in HEAD and modified in revision

Tags: git

Pretty new to git and have a bit of an issue i'm not sure how to fix. I mistakenly made a change to one file in a working copy and didn't commit the change. I then made changes to another copy and committed them - when I tried to pull the changes I unsurprisingly got an error saying my "local changes to the file would be overwritten by merge, aborting". So I removed the offending file using git rm, then used git add -u and committed the deletion. I then tried to pull in the latest copy and got the following. What's the best way to deal with this? grateful for any pointers

```
CONFLICT (delete/modify): wp-content/plugins/wp-flash-countdown/xml_option_.xml deleted in HEAD and modified in ba878ab1efe3a039961a446c490d5c93a2bc22e1. Version ba878ab1efe3a039961a446c490d5c93a2bc22e1 of wp-content/plugins/wp-flash-countdown/xml_option_.xml left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git - merge conflict when local is deleted but file exists in remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319486/git-merge-conflict-when-local-is-deleted-but-file-exists-in-remote)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SO at this point do you have the file in the working copy that you pulled to?

if so just delete it and recommit.

Comment: I just tried that, recommitted and then pulled again - this time geting `Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'` -  it also listed as adding files which i'd just removed from that working copy as they weren't being tracked

Comment: ok, so it is just that one file that's causing the problem - tried to delete with git rm but get a "needs merge" error

Comment: in the end, got it sorted, with effectively your solution and a few needless extra steps from me!

Answer (score 15):

If you now do `git status`, its output contains:

```
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
```

If you `git rm` them, a `needs merge` warning will be output but nevertheless the removal will succeed, then you can commit the modifications - this will be the "merge commit".

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem with a cheesy WordPress host. Try this..

```
git log --follow -- readme.html
```

Note the commit id of the last time that file existed (like before you deleted it.) Now you want to "checkout" that file from git.

```
git checkout (commit id) readme.html
```

Then add, commit, push, etc. Worked for me!

Comment: This worked well for me, thank you.