# How to accept 'your' changes when doing git merge?

Tags: git

I'm trying to merge from a source branch that has deleted some of the files that've been modified in the target branch. I want to ignore the deletions and simply accept what the destination branch already has.

When I:

```
git merge -s recursive -X ours master
```

the output of `git status` is:

```
# On branch nyap-artifactory
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   new file:   file-re-added-by-source-branch-that-should-be-deleted
#   modified:   file-modified-by-source-branch
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   deleted by them:    file-deleted-by-source-branch-that-should-be-kept
```

What's the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git add file-name and the commit the merge.
Similar question here with further explanation: [git - merge conflict when local is deleted but file exists in remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319486/git-merge-conflict-when-local-is-deleted-but-file-exists-in-remote)

Comment: Keith, if you can't spare the time to actually explain things, it's more suitable as a comment

Comment: I apologize. Will follow that advice for now on, but was actually unable to leave comments until the reputation awarded for last answer

Comment: good point, I keep forgetting about those 'privileges' :) Welcome to SO as a contributor!

Answer (score 2):

You should just re-add the file to the index:

```
git checkout HEAD -- file-deleted-by-source-branch-that-should-be-kept
```

and commit the merge.

What this does is get the latest version from the `nyap-artifactory` branch. [*]

---

[*] (A `git reset -- file-deleted-by-source-branch-that-should-be-kept` might be enough, but is a bit trickier to work with, since it doesn't necessarily update the working tree, and has options that are powerful enough to accidentally lose data).