# GIT: How dangerous is "deleted by us" conflict?

Tags: git

A few days ago I made a new branch called "new_branch" based on "master". While I worked on my "new_branch" with file "file.php", a second developer on his branch deleted the file "file.php" and merged his branch with "master". Now I need to rebase my branch on current "master". After the command `git pull --rebase origin master` I have the conflict

> deleted by us:   app/file.php

I don't know what to do, I don't want to lose changes I've made in this file. After commands

```
git add -A
git rebase --continue
```

will the file disappear in my "new_branch"?

Comment: If you already commit this file in at least one commit, then it will stay here "forever" (unless you loose all references to this commit and invoke Git garbage collection).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git - merge conflict when local is deleted but file exists in remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319486/git-merge-conflict-when-local-is-deleted-but-file-exists-in-remote)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The message `deleted by us: app/file.php` means precisely what you described, namely that someone deleted this file in the `master` branch on which you are rebasing `new_branch`.

Assuming that the delete has not yet been staged and you want to keep this file, then you should `git add` the file to mark it that it should be kept:

```
git add app/file.php
```

Then, resolve all other merge conflicts and do `git rebase --continue`

Note that if you wanted to accept the delete you would do `git rm` instead.

Comment: "deleted by us" means it was deleted by "them"?

Comment: @xaxxon See this [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025314/who-is-us-and-who-is-them-according-to-git) for an explanation.  In a rebase, "us" becomes the branch against which you are applying the commits, which is when the merge conflict due to the deleted file occurs.