# What exactly does "git diff --base" do?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

My notes say the function of `git diff --base` is to "View the conflicts against the base file (the point where the two branches started diverting the considered file)" but I am not being able to visualize this without any example. How does this differ from the normal `git diff` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `git diff --base` makes sense only for files that are in a conflicted state, for example, during a merge, or a cherry-pick, or a rebase.

When there is a conflict in file `foo`, there are three versions recorded in the index: the "base" version, "their" version, and "our" version. The "base" version is indeed the version of the file where the  two branches started diverging, as you have written in your notes.

Thus, when you type

```
git diff --base foo
```

you see the difference of the current version of `foo` in the worktree to the base version.

Similarly, you can use

```
git diff --theirs foo
git diff --ours foo
```

to see the difference to the other two versions involved in the conflict.